# Does macOS have an API for Siri?

Tags: siri, sirikit, macos-sierra

Can I program a macOS app with Siri functionality like I can with an iOS app?

As in, for example, play a sound using my music app when telling Siri "play the Aurora sound", or any other thing that SiriKit can do on [ios](/questions/tagged/ios).

Comment: @JAL and all the others who flagged this as a duplicate: that is tagged with iOS, and this is tagged with macOS. Two different operating systems.

Comment: I'm afraid that if the question ain't a duplicate, it may be too broad or fall into off-topic for asking a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf, it has to be yes or no, so it can't possibly be too broad.  And off-topic... just no.

Comment: This question is useful. Not a dupe and not too broad.

Comment: To those who falsely claim this is a duplicate: when the other question was asked, Siri ONLY existed in iOS, and therefore the question *could only be about iOS*.  This question is _specifically and explicitly_ about macOS.  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206993 They cannot possibly be considered duplicates.

Comment: @iconoclast Thank you for saying that! SiriKit didn't exist on either platform when the other question was asked too.

Comment: @haykam You're welcome.  All the people who _carelessly_ close questions as duplicates, just because they have the power to, but can't be bothered to actually read and understand the questions, are doing great damage to the stack exchange sites.

Answer (score 9):

> As in, for example, play a sound using my music app when telling Siri "play the Aurora sound".

The example you posted will not be possible on iOS either, as SiriKit is [restricted to only very few uses cases](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875).

The documentation did not mention this at the time of this question's asking, but was [updated later](https://web.archive.org/web/20170616054043/https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit) to say it supports `macOS 10.12+`:

> **SDKs**
>
> iOS 10.0+
> macOS 10.12+
> watchOS 3.2+

Also [macOS 10.12 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/Miscellaneous/APIDiffsMacOS10_12/index.html) do not mention SiriKit — though intents are supported. Maybe we will see SiriKit with later betas. And if that happens, I hope there will be fewer restrictions on iOS as-well, because with the current restrictions it won't make much sense to have SiriKit on desktop computers.

Comment: Intents are in the release note.

Comment: that is interesting.

Comment: The docs don't mention it, but it's there in some form or another. The difference is that it somehow seems to interface with Spotlight db metadata to interact with the filesystem. http://www.apple.com/macos/sierra/